# Dot preceding parentheses, .( ), in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, kaggle

I am not familiar with this `df[, .(...), Col]` notation. I apologize if I am missing something obvious, but I cannot find a reference to this notation style, though it looks very useful.

It appears to be implementing aggregation. Based on the location of this notation in the code below, I would expect it to come from R not from `h2o` but I have tried checking both to no avail.

The example is from a Kaggle competition and the code works (to reproduce it [go here](https://www.kaggle.com/mlandry/how-much-did-it-rain-ii/h2o-starter/code)):

```
trainHex<-as.h2o(train[,.(
  dist   = mean(radardist_km, na.rm = T),
  refArea5   = mean(Ref_5x5_50th, na.rm = T),
  refArea9  = mean(Ref_5x5_90th, na.rm = T),
  meanRefcomp = mean(RefComposite,na.rm=T),
  meanRefcomp5 = mean(RefComposite_5x5_50th,na.rm=T),
  meanRefcomp9 = mean(RefComposite_5x5_90th,na.rm=T),
  zdr   = mean(Zdr, na.rm = T),
  zdr5   = mean(Zdr_5x5_50th, na.rm = T),
  zdr9   = mean(Zdr_5x5_90th, na.rm = T),
  target = log1p(mean(Expected)),
  meanRef = mean(Ref,na.rm=T),
  sumRef = sum(Ref,na.rm=T),
  records = .N,
  naCounts = sum(is.na(Ref))
),Id][records>naCounts,],destination_frame="train.hex")
```

I would love the documentation and/or a good explanation of this.

Comment: This is `data.table` syntax (see line 24 of the code you linked and see ?data.table::data.table for more). Since 1.9.5, `.(...)` is an alias for `list(...)`.

Comment: At line 30 the `data.table` is created. The function `fread` defaults to that structure.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.()` is a **data.table** convenience function, acting as a terse alias for `list()`. Complicating matters just a little bit (mostly for those, like you, trying to figure out what the heck that `.` does!) is the fact that it's only interpreted as such within the scope of a call to  `[.data.table()`.

Here, from `?data.table`:

```
 DT = data.table(x=rep(c("a","b","c"),each=3), y=c(1,3,6), v=1:9)
 setkey(DT,x,y)             # 2-column key

 DT["a"]                    # join to 1st column of key
 DT[.("a")]                 # same, .() is an alias for list()
 DT[list("a")]              # same

 ## But note that *this* doesn't work (my addition --- not in ?data.table)
 .("a")
```

See also the vignette [Introduction to data.table](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html):

> `data.table` also allows wrapping columns with `.()` instead of `list()`. It is an alias to `list()`; they both mean the same. Feel free to use whichever you prefer

Comment: I knew that my stubborn refusal to become more familiar with `data.table` would haunt me! Thanks much

Comment: @Hack-R Arun's [vignettes](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started) are a great place to get your feet wet

Comment: @MichaelChirico Thanks, yea I checked the vignettes I thought might be related, I just didn't realize which vignette was related to this. It's not something you can find out with a simple `?` as you can the name of a function to see which package it's associated with.